# Syntax for multiple protocols

Tags: objective-c

What is the Objective-C syntax for multiple protocols?

Comment: What do you mean by "multiple delegates"?  If you want more than one delegate, you specify more than one using the normal syntax.  I'm guessing that isn't what you meant though?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Could you please elaborate on your question?  Otherwise this is the proper way to declare a class that conforms to multiple protocols.  You specify the protocols a class conforms to after the superclass declaration in a classes header file.

```
@interface MyClass : MySuperClass <Delegate1, Delegate2, Delegate3> {
     //instance variables
}

//properties

//methods
```

Comment: Thanks. I thought it was <delegate1>, <delegate2> for some reason. thanks

Comment: Those are protocols, not delegates.  Often, a class that requires a delegate will define a protocol that has "delegate" in its name.  This is because it is a protocol that the *delegate* has to conform to.  That's why you see "delegate" there so often, not because they are delegates.

Comment: Also, it's really quick to find the answers to these sorts of questions yourself.  Go to [the iOS Dev Center](http://developer.apple.com/devcenter/ios/index.action) and read [Learning Objective-C: A Primer](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#referencelibrary/GettingStarted/Learning_Objective-C_A_Primer/).  The answer's right there at the bottom of the page.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve multiple protocols in two ways:

**Method 1**

```
@protocol p1 <NSObject>
-(void)M1
-(void)M2
@end

@protocol p2 <NSObject>
-(void)M3
-(void)M4
@end

@interface MyViewController () <p1,p2>
```

**Method 2**

```
@protocol p1 <NSObject>
-(void)M1
-(void)M2
@end

@protocol p2 <NSObject,p1>
-(void)M3
-(void)M4
@end

@interface MyViewController () <p1>
```

Answer (score 0):

For an object to have multiple delegates (as opposed to being a delegate for multiple objects or classes):

1. The object delegating would have to
   have an NSArray of delegate instance
   variables.
2. The setDelegate setter method would
   then have to add a delegate object
   to this array instead of just
   assigning it to one instance
   variable.
3. The send-to-delegate code would have
   to loop through the delegate
   NSArray, instead of checking for
   just one delegate instance variable
   to be non-nil, before checking for
   message handling and calling out
   with the message.

Nothing much would change in all the objects or the class asking for delegation to itself.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I guess the question of comfort to multi protocols is something like the following:

```
@interface MyViewController () <protocol1, protocol2, protocol3>
```